# Want to remove space between containers

Tags: html, css

I have created a top bar menu (colored in light green) and a navigation menu (dark green). There is a black space between both. This is the background here is the header (.site-header). I have tried using margin: 0px on this element amongst others but no joy.

Child elements of both the top bar and main nav menu's are set to display: inline-block.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Music Website</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Music Website">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content= "1.5">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

</head>

<body>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

    <header class="site-header">
        <div class="top-bar">
            <ul>
                <li class="top-bar-items"><i class="material-icons">call</i>Phone: 088-888-8888<a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="top-bar-items"><i class="material-icons">email</i>Email: info@music.com<a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="top-bar-items"><i class="material-icons">access_time</i>Opening Hours: Mon - Fri 9am - 5.30pm<a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>
        <div class="site-body">
            <div class="main"></div>
                <aside class="sidebar"></aside>
            </div>

    <footer class="site-footer">
        <p></p>
    </footer>       

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.site-header {
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0px;
}

.top-bar {
    background-color: springgreen;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-bar ul {
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.top-bar li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.top-bar-items {
    margin: 0px;
}

/*.top-bar:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}*/

.top-bar-items i {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

nav {
    background-color: seagreen;
    height: 100px;

}

nav li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        background-color: orange;
        padding: 5px;
}
```

**Image Of PAGE**

[Top Bar & Main Nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vqnm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your CSS:

```css
      *{
          padding: 0%;
          margin: 0%;
      }
```

It fixed it for me!

Comment: But will reset all padding and margin in `*` I think

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem into *user agent stylesheet*
in `user agent stylesheet`

**This a your problem in User Agent Style Sheet**

```
ul {
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-block-start: 1em;
margin-block-end: 1em;
margin-inline-start: 0px;
margin-inline-end: 0px;
padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
```

Then I'm added Css code in `nav` with

```
nav ul {
margin-block-start: 0em!important;
margin-block-end: 0em!important;
}
```

**So I get Result like this**

```css
.site-header {
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0px;
}

.top-bar {
    background-color: springgreen;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-bar ul {
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.top-bar li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.top-bar-items {
    margin: 0px;
}

/*.top-bar:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}*/

.top-bar-items i {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

nav {
    background-color: seagreen;
    height: 100px;
}
nav ul {
    margin-block-start: 0em!important;
    margin-block-end: 0em!important;
}
nav li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        background-color: orange;
        padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Music Website</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Music Website">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

    <header class="site-header">
        <div class="top-bar">
            <ul>
                <li class="top-bar-items"><i class="material-icons">call</i>Phone: 088-888-8888<a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="top-bar-items"><i class="material-icons">email</i>Email: info@music.com<a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="top-bar-items"><i class="material-icons">access_time</i>Opening Hours: Mon - Fri 9am - 5.30pm<a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>
        <div class="site-body">
            <div class="main"></div>
                <aside class="sidebar"></aside>
            </div>

    <footer class="site-footer">
        <p></p>
    </footer>       

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The margin you are getting is from the ul which is applied as default styling from browser.

To fix this, you should reset the css.

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

[image]
Here is a better version of css reset and also a little description to help you understand what is reset css.
https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Also, if you inspect element, you can see that default styling.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your stylesheet:

```
nav ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```